# How do you detect a keycombo in a toolbar text box?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I want to detect the keycombo CTRL+ENTER in my toolbar text field and run a function.
I notice currently the default when ENTER is hit that it does on command, so I need the keycombo to fire before the oncommand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to the field (`true` makes the handler trigger in the [*capturing phase*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)) :

```
element.addEventListener('keydown', eventHandler, true);
```

where `eventHandler` looks like

```
function eventHandler(event) {
    if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === KeyEvent.DOM_VK_RETURN) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // stop event bubbling here
        event.preventDefault(); // don't execute default action
        // do something
    }
}
```

[*List of possible `keyCode`s*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/KeyEvent).